# Pycharm Terminal can't activate Conda environment

Tags: python, encoding, anaconda, environment

I'm running python 3.7 and have miniconda3 installed on macOS. I'm using Pycharm community 2019.2. When I start up a new Pycharm Terminal, I get the following error, and the relevant Conda environment can't be activated :

```
      File "/Users/me/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/activate.py", line 996, in main
    print(activator.execute(), end='')
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u279c' in position 28: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I have looked for similar posts but can't find the solution. The Conda environment works fine in iTerm, but there seems to be a problem with Pycharm's terminal. I've looked at the method in Conda's source code that parses the problematic argument:

```
def main(argv=None):
from .common.compat import init_std_stream_encoding

context.__init__()  # On import, context does not include SEARCH_PATH. This line fixes that.

init_std_stream_encoding()
argv = argv or sys.argv
assert len(argv) >= 3
assert argv[1].startswith('shell.')
shell = argv[1].replace('shell.', '', 1)
activator_args = argv[2:]
try:
    activator_cls = activator_map[shell]
except KeyError:
    raise CondaError("%s is not a supported shell." % shell)
activator = activator_cls(activator_args)
try:
    print(activator.execute(), end='')
    return 0
except Exception as e:
    if isinstance(e, CondaError):
        print(text_type(e), file=sys.stderr)
        return e.return_code
    else:
        raise
```

- But I can't figure out where these arguments come from in the first place. Does anyone know what the issue is?

Comment: Maybe the encoding of the Terminal Emulator used in Pycharm doesn't support some of the encoding used in Conda. Have you tried setting another encoding in the Plugin for the Terminal? Maybe opening a support ticket if the option doesn't exists could help too.

Comment: @Cobalt In the end I re-installed Miniconda3 and that did it. It remains a mystery, but thanks for the suggestion!